Google Sheet Query Sort with Order by DateTime
I have database in Google Sheets, Let's say the named sheet is Raw Sugar. In Sheet Raw Sugar, I have data in the range Raw Sugar'!A2:F as pictured below:

Then, i have other sheet, the named sheet is "Sugar". My goal is i want to query from Sheet Raw Sugar to Sheet Sugar. I tried to query with sort using ORDER BY based on column F but didn't work. Looks like the query formula doesn't work on DateTime format.
Before that i have created formula but it not worked. Following my formula :
=QUERY('Raw Sugar'!A2:F; "Select A, B, C, D, E, F Order by F")
Here is my link sheet if you want to see it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OsIBLn-VohJRnc2Xz2eRdZwrK79s5f1vncHVmiqCQ2w/edit?usp=sharing
Please advise me how I can fix the formula to correct this sheet. Thankyou


You may try:
=query('Raw Sugar'!A2:F; "Where F is not null Order by F")



try:
=SORT('Raw Sugar'!A2:F; 6; 1)


